How do i edit the codepen FlipDown.js Countdown?
I found this countdown clock in CodePen, but I need to edit it, I need to set the final date to May 30, 2024. ¿Does anybody know how to set up the final date?


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

  // Unix timestamp (in seconds) to count down to
  var twoDaysFromNow = (new Date().getTime() / 1000) + (86400 * 2) + 1;

  // Set up FlipDown
  var flipdown = new FlipDown(twoDaysFromNow)

    // Start the countdown
    .start()

    // Do something when the countdown ends
    .ifEnded(() => {
      console.log('The countdown has ended!');
    });

  // Toggle theme
  var interval = setInterval(() => {
    let body = document.body;
    body.classList.toggle('light-theme');
    body.querySelector('#flipdown').classList.toggle('flipdown__theme-dark');
    body.querySelector('#flipdown').classList.toggle('flipdown__theme-light');
  }, 5000);
  
  var ver = document.getElementById('ver');
  ver.innerHTML = flipdown.version;
});



Or anybody can tell me where ¿I can find a flip countdown easy to set up?
THANKS

Get the timestamp with milliseconds of May 30, 2024, then turn it to seconds by dividing by 1000, and pass it to the FlipDown constructor
const finalDate = new Date('2024-05-30T00:00:00Z').getTime() / 1000;

  // Set up FlipDown
const flipdown = new FlipDown(finalDate)

    // Start the countdown
    .start()

    // Do something when the countdown ends
    .ifEnded(() => {
      console.log('The countdown has ended!');
    });


Thank you so much, it works you can see it here: https://www.cumbrelaboral.co/

86400 * 2 is meant to be 2 days in seconds

24 hours a day
60 minute in the hour
60 second in the minute

so one day is (24 * 60 * 60 = 86400)
and 2 days is (2 * 86400)
review the docs

Thanks for your explication
